# Given a conditional probability, find $P(A)$

Tags: probability

Given that $P(B) = 0.8$ , $P(A\mid B) = 0.2$ and $P(A\mid B^{\complement}) = 0.3$.

> **Find $P(A)$**.

So, $P(B^{\complement}) = 0,2$ and I already know that $P(A) = P(A \cap\ B) + P(A \cap\ B^c)$

After this I don't know what to do.

Comment: It is not true that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A \cup B)$.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see well what I wrote. Just corrected now. Thank you!

Comment: It's also not true that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^{\mathsf{c}})$.

Comment: I misunderstood my notes here. tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $A$ is partitioned by $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B^{\mathsf{c}}$, so that
$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap B^{\mathsf{c}})$$
Now apply the definition of conditional probability to write $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B^{\mathsf{c}})$ in terms of $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ and $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B^{\mathrm{c}})$.

Comment: So I'd have $P(A/B) = P(A \cap\ B)/ P(B)$, so $P(A \cap\ B) = P(A/B) * P(B)$ which is equal to $0.16$. Thus, doing the same with $P(A \cap\ B^c)$ results in $0.06$. Finally, $P(A)$ is $0.22$.